# Why did a moderator remove multiple answers to append them to the question?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, specific-answer, specific-edit

Here is the question: [Can I ellipse a clipping mask on the bottom only?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30766857/8620333)

It sounds a bit strange when you read it, but if you check the [revisions](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/30766857/revisions) and the deleted answers you can clearly see what is going on. For users who cannot see the deleted answers, each *attempt* was a single answer (so a total of 6 answers from the same user).

I am pretty convinced that the moderator did a mistake editing the question instead of the non deleted answer, but probably not so I wanted to verify if this is *really* a mistake or intentional?

If it's intentional, why?

**UPDATE**

For me the asker is providing 6 different ways to achieve the same goal and simply calling them *attempt* and for each one giving the downside. Having all of them posted as answers means that they were meant to be different answers and should not belong to the question, but to one answer that hold them all.

Comment: This whole Q&A is weird. OP themselves calls them just an attempt with corresponding issue(s), thus they may not satisfy their requirements, but you could also rename them "answers" and each one of them just has downsites and someone else may not bother about them.

Comment: @Tom if we consider the initial state where the asker gives all of them as answers, I guess the purpose was to make them all different answers

Comment: What is the purpose of self answering a question 6 times with answers that have issues and don't fully work?

Comment: @JoeW all the answers works but have downsides they call them *issues* even in the attempt 6 kept as answer

Comment: Pinging the editing mod would more productive than posting in meta, IMO. It's a 4 years old affair anyway, I doubt it's fresh in Brad's mind.

Comment: The passage of 4 years is exactly why you *wouldn’t* ping Brad, @yivi. To other moderators or experienced users, the motivation for his actions should be self-evident. If they’re not, and we determine him to have made a mistake, we can simply correct it. There doesn’t need to be any focus on or even mention of who the original moderator was. (Also, Brad’s busy with Real Life, and I really don’t think this is worth his attention right now.)

Comment: Disagree @Cody (in a general sense, not because I like pinging mods, or because I think Brad is in any way obliged to respond). I believe the way the question is framed only Brad can answer it. Other users (diamonds or not) can offer (pretty  well informed) guesses and opinions, but only the specific moderator can answer it. It is possible to frame the question in such a way that can be answered by the community, but only the actor can really answer "was this a mistake or was it intentional".

Comment: Was self answering not popular back then ?

Answer (score 14):

Because they were attempts by the OP, not answers.

An attempt does not answer the question, it's part of the question.

Comment: they all are attempts and I am pretty sure he wanted to give the 6 attempts as different answers, this is common in CSS. Ex: https://stackoverflow.com/q/30441122/8620333

Comment: Then maybe it should just have been one long answer. _"Here's 6 different options that all aren't perfect."_

Comment: For me that was the mistake of the asker who made 6 answers instead of a big one.

Comment: It's been a few years, but I think this was my general thought process. The answers were flagged as "not an answer", and I believe that I interpreted them as a continued evolution of the question. That's why I converted them into edits in sequence. If people believe these could live as standalone answers, I'd be glad to roll back the edits and undelete the answers. Don't know if the next step would be to combine those into one large answer.